# a pair of number enclosed in parentheses

Tags: c++

Here is a block of code. Can anyone explain what it means to have a pair of numbers enclosed inside parentheses. (This is in C++.)

```
    int a = 2, b = 2, c = 3, d = 1;
    if((a,b)<(c,d))
        cout<<"case1"<<endl;
    else
        cout<<"case2";
```

Comment: Most probably an error. The compiler will process that as the comma operator, but that means that the expression is equivalent to `if(b,d)`... I doubt the programmer just wanted to do a couple extra useless key presses...

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: you mean `if(b<d)`, right? IMO, it looks like the author wanted to do a tuple compare (like you can in other languages, e.g. Python), and believed it worked when the code compiled successfully.

Comment: Let me guess: interview question ?

Comment: @nneonneo: Yes, I should avoid reading code after midnight :)

Comment: @David: I came across this block of code when trying to understand Lamport's bakery algorithm, which is a solution to critical section problem.

Answer (score 13):

That's the *comma operator*; it evaluates the thing on the left, throws the result out, and returns the result on the right. Since evaluating an `int` variable has no side-effects, that `if` is semantically equivalent to

```
if(b < d)
```

Answer (score -2):

Or if the value are changing or taken as an input by user you can use `&&` (and), `||` (or) logical operators to sort out your codes

`if ((a<c) && (b<d))`

or

`if ((a<c) || (b<d))`

That way you can make cases the way you like. Check about operators here http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/operators/